# How to import table's clob data type column along with other columns to Hadoop

Tags: sql, apache-spark, sqoop

Have a table in oracle with total 11 columns, out of those 1 column data type CLOB. When we import table into hadoop,CLOB column datatype will get converted to string, But we want in a format where we can aceess values using attibute

Comment: Below link may help you  https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49145/how-to-sqoop-import-oracle-blobclob-data-into-hive.html